why can't c++ Open3D Application “find resource directory”?
I am using Open3D (0.18.0+) from C++, and having some troubles adjusting properties in ViewControl.
I have been using open3d::visualization::Visualizer — which is apparently considered “legacy” — versus say open3d::visualization::gui::Application. I would prefer to use the newer Application class, but I have problems with that too.
This code using the legacy Visualizer works, showing a window with a red ball in the center:
void test()
{
    open3d::PrintOpen3DVersion();
    auto vis = open3d::visualization::Visualizer();
    vis.CreateVisualizerWindow();
    auto ball = open3d::geometry::TriangleMesh::CreateSphere(5);
    ball->ComputeVertexNormals();
    ball->PaintUniformColor({1, 0, 0});
    vis.AddGeometry(ball);
    vis.Run();
}

While there seems to be very little Open3D example code in C++, there is a fair amount in Python. Most of it uses the modern Application class. Not wanting to go against the flow, I tried something similar using that newer class:
void test2()
{
    
    open3d::PrintOpen3DVersion();
    open3d::visualization::gui::Application::GetInstance().Initialize();
    auto vis = open3d::visualization::visualizer::O3DVisualizer("name", 500, 500);
    auto ball = open3d::geometry::TriangleMesh::CreateSphere(5);
    ball->ComputeVertexNormals();
    ball->PaintUniformColor({1, 0, 0});
    vis.AddGeometry("ball", {ball});
    open3d::visualization::gui::Application::GetInstance().Run();
}

That gets “Could not find resource directory”:
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error:
[Open3D Error] (std::string (anonymous namespace)::FindResourcePath(int, 
const char **)) 
/Users/cwr/Documents/code/Open3D/cpp/open3d/visualization/gui/
Application.cpp:96: Could not find resource directory.

What is the resource directory, what needs to be in it, and how do I set that up?
It would be super helpful to see modern example C++ code using the Application class.
